# How can I make a sequence with entered values by button in Java?

Tags: java, user-interface, listener, actionlistener

I want write program who in t1(TextField) enter how many numbers user want enter and confirm by b1(Button). In t2(TextField) user give a first value and enter it by b2(Button), in next time user give a second value and again enter it by b2(Button). It happens so much times as high is n (from first listener).

How must I change code that program to do it?

Now when i give to t2 first value and hit the button then b2 is still pressed and user can't do anything.

```
final AtomicInteger n = new AtomicInteger();
ActionListener lis5 = new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String a = t1.getText();
        n.set(Integer.parseInt(a));
    } 
};
b1.addActionListener(lis5); 

ActionListener lis6 = new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //String b = t2.getText();     ??
        //n.set(Integer.parseInt(b));  ??

        int nn = n.get();
        int [] tab = new int[nn];
        for(int i=0;i<nn;i++){
            tab[i] = in.nextInt();
        }
    } 
};
b2.addActionListener(lis6);
```

Comment: You could use JOptionPane's showInputDialog in a counter-controlled loop.

Comment: If `in.nextInt()` is reading fom a `Scanner`, the thread will block until there is an integer to read. Is this what you are doing ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, get rid of the for loop in the ActionListener. For loops work for linear console programs where you enter data using a Scanner but not for event-driven GUI's. Here instead of the for loop use a counter int variable that you increment within the ActionListener and that you use to help you decide where to place the data. Also get the int array **out** of the ActionListener and into the class so that it can be available to the rest of the class. In pseudocode:

```
in the class
    int array declared here BUT not initialized here.

    first Actionlistener
        get total count value
        initialize array using this value
    end first action listener

    second ActionListener
        int counter variable set to 0.
        action performed method
            if counter < total count
                get value from text field
                convert it to an int
                place value into intArray[counter]
                increment counter
            end if
        end action performed
    end second ActionLisener
```

Comment: @belusa16: he's using an array,`int [] tab = new int[nn];` and so I continued that in the answer above, but yes, better would be to use the more flexible `ArrayList<Integer>` since that could be initialized immediately as he wouldn't have to know the total count to do this.